# How to use service with AsyncTask?

Tags: android, sockets, service, websocket, android-asynctask

How to use Android `Service` with `AsyncTask`? Is it possible (or) not possible?

I am trying to implement socket message receiver. Am already UI thread and `AsyncTask` use to socket message receiver created but my application is working slowly, so I need any other solution.

```
Runnable mHandlerTask;
Handler mHandler;

void init() {
    mHandler = new Handler();
    mHandlerTask = new Runnable(){
        @Override
        public void run(){
            Scoketvalue_Reciver();
            mHandler.postDelayed(mHandlerTask, INTERVAL);
        }
    };
}

private void Scoketvalue_Reciver() {
    new MainActivity.FileServerAsyncTask(this,info).execute();
}

void startRepeatingTask(){
    mHandlerTask.run();
}

void stopRepeatingTask(){
    mHandler.removeCallbacks(mHandlerTask);
}



public FileServerAsyncTask(Context context , WifiP2pInfo info){
            this.context = context;
            this.info = info;
        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(Void... params){
            try{
                ServerSocket serverSocket;
                serverSocket = new ServerSocket(8988);
                Socket client = serverSocket.accept();
                Log.d("vishnu ","getInetAddress ::"+client.getInetAddress());
                if(info.isGroupOwner) {
                    Utils.clientipAddress = String.valueOf(client.getInetAddress().getHostAddress());
                }
                BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(client.getInputStream()));
                String st = null;
                st = input.readLine();
                serverSocket.close();
                return st;
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.e(TAG, e.getMessage());
                return null;
            }
        }

        /*
         * (non-Javadoc)
         * @see android.os.AsyncTask#onPostExecute(java.lang.Object)
         */
        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
            if (result != null) {
                Toast.makeText(context.getApplicationContext(),"value "+result,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                MainActivity.sentpickedholeid(result);
//              statusText.setText("File copied - " + result);
            }
        }

        /*
         * (non-Javadoc)
         * @see android.os.AsyncTask#onPreExecute()
         */
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
//          statusText.setText("Opening a server socket");
        }
    }
```

Comment: Did you try the solution I proposed?

Answer (score 0):

**I would recommend using [WebSocket from okhttp](http://square.github.io/okhttp/3.x/okhttp/), developed by Square, instead of using your own implementation based on AsyncTasks or Threads.**

You need to initialize WebSocket in `onCreate()` method and implement a `WebSocketListener` to receive messages/errors from socket:

```
public class YourService extends Service {
    WebSocket ws;

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        startWebSocket();
    }

    private void startWebSocket() {
        Request request = new Request.Builder().url("ws://echo.websocket.org").build();
        WebSocketListener listener = new YourWebSocketListener();
        ws = client.newWebSocket(request, listener);
    }
}
```

Check [this official square example](https://github.com/square/okhttp/blob/master/samples/guide/src/main/java/okhttp3/recipes/WebSocketEcho.java) to understand how to implement `YourWebSocketListener`.